# Magnolia CMS: how to configure proxy and bypasses

Tags: java, content-management-system, http-proxy, magnolia

I'm developing a Magnolia module which will include some RSS feeds as well as some webservice calls to an internal client system.

My company has a web proxy, so for the RSS feeds to gather data, I have configured the Tomcat server with the proxy details: added the following JVM args to CATALINE_OPTS in setenv.bat:

```
    -Dhttp.proxyHost=%hostname% -Dhttp.proxyPort=%port% -Dhttp.proxyUser=%user% -Dhttp.proxyPass=%passwd%
```

My RSS Aggregator now works, but my webservice calls fail with 403 Forbidden. Assuming this is because of the proxy, as it I remove the JVM args, the calls work again.

Now my questions:

1. How do I configure proxy bypasses to my webservice host domain (i.e. *.intws.co.uk) in Tomcat?
2. Is there a way to configure the proxy details in Magnolia? My clients will have different proxy settings which I want them to managed (in Magnolia rather than Tomcat files).
3. Can bypass hosts also be configured in Magnolia? Again my clients might have their web services installed under different hostnames.

My knowledge of Tomcat config and proxies in general are limited, so please feel free to go into as more detail as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need, but maybe having a look at virtual URI mapping could help:
You find those options inside Magnolia in the Admin Interface in `Configuration:modules/adminInterface/virtualURIMapping` (or click on "Default URI"). It's also good to know that Magnolia EE is more powerful here than CE.

More info: http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/technical-guide/virtual-uri-mapping.html